# Symfony Form: How to replace form class / retrieve all extra data?

Tags: php, json, forms, rest, symfony

The Symfony 2 Form Component really is something. I guess you know that. Trying to understand what works how is just an seemingly impossible task; and I'm quite experienced at browsing through codebases.. But man, the Form component.. OMG

**TL;DR**

Below are details, this issue tries to ask

- Is it possible to replace the class `\Symfony\Component\Form\Form`?
- Or: How to easily get all extra data from all fields of type form of a form?
- Or, a related question: How on earth does it work that if i do `$form->add('ss', 'form')` - obviously the `Core\FormType` class gets involved but when i retrieve it later, it is an instance of `\Symfony\Component\Form\Form`? Where does that happen and can this maybe overriden so it uses a different class there?

**Details**

*The situation*

Imagine a Controller that receives a n deep JSON payload. This payload gets decoded and validated through Form. Now, most of this JSON structure is mapped by Models (Doctrine ODM Entities). But some sub-properties are just "hashes" - the client is allowed to post whatever he wants there.
Those "hash" subproperties are fields of type form, are compound flagged and can have extra fields.

*The problem*

Bottom line our problem is, that all "extra fields" are not returned by `$form->getData()`. We are unable to specify those fields (and their types) as we don't know what will come - so all this data is part of extraData.

*The solution?*

So i thought - OK - let's modify the FormFactory so it'll return our Custom extension of Form - one that also returns extraData when getData is called. Easy right.? Noo, not easy..

My idea let me inspect FormFactory, the FormBuilders, the ResolvedFormTypes, whatnot.. and at all important places (like `formBuilder->getForm()`) - the classes I want to override/replace are instanciated static - no usage of the DIC..(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read somewhere that the Form component in Symfony 2 was written by the devil himself to let we developer go mad. Luckily I'm not so mad to try to replace the entire Form component by myself ;)

Jokes aside, when you define a form (by creating a `<entity>Type` class, like `UserType`) you are defining a new type that can be as simple as a single text input or as complex as full-fledged form (our `UserType` from before). The "real" form (`Symfony\Component\Form\Form`) is created from your type definition:

```
return $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(
    new UserType(), new User(), $options
);
```

Have you evaluated the idea to create a custom form type for your "extraData"? Or maybe it can be mapped as a JSON string that's created by a client-side JavaScript before submit.

Comment: This indeed is the right way to go.. Although I figured it out after asking the question. So learn: If one wants to store big flexible structures from JSON payloads, one shall define a FormType extending ` Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType` (like `class FreeForm extends AbstractType`) - then have `getParent()` return `text` and you can basically store inside what you desire.